# Can anyone help me solve this?

Tags: quadratics

Two taps A and B can fill a swimming pool in $3$ hours. If turned on alone, it takes tap A $5$ hours less than tap B to fill the same pool. How many hours does it take tap A to fill the pool?
\begin{align*}
3(A+B) & = x\\
\frac{x}{B} - \frac{x}{A} & = 5
\end{align*}

Can anyone show me some hints?

Comment: I have tried but i don't get anything. There are 2 unknowns. So, I'm finding another equation to solve it simultaneously. But, failed anyways.

Comment: So you have found one equation already, what is it?

Comment: Can you please show me your solution?

Comment: That's not what this site is about... We're happy to help here but we won't just spoon feed you an answer

Comment: $3(A+B)=x$      $x/B - x/A=5$

Comment: sorry there are 2

Comment: Add these to your question by editing it and explain the problem you have, you'll get a much better response

Comment: Can you show a hint for next step?

Comment: What is x here?

Comment: I create another unknown. x is the total capacity of the swimming pool.

Comment: I take the A and B as the rate of filling the water.

Comment: $$3A^2-5AB-3B^2=0$$
After combining both equations.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you have a tap that fills the pool in $t_1$ hours and another than fills the pool in $t_2$ hours, how much time will they take to fill the pool if they're turned on together? This is the heart of the problem, work that out as its own problem and then use what you find to solve the original problem. You should find that with both taps running, you'll take

$$t=\frac {t_1t_2} {t_1 + t_2}$$

hours to fill up the pool.

You're also falling into a common trap for beginners. The problem mentions several different quantities, so you instinctively write down variable names for all of them, and make the problem more complicated than it needs to be. This problem only requires one variable (and only one equation), not two and certainly not three. In the second sentence, they say, if $t_1$ is the time tap A takes and $t_2$ is the time tap B takes, that $t_1=t_2-5$. So you don't *need* both variables, any time you would normally write down $t_1$ just replace it with $t_2 - 5$.

---

To derive the relation $t=\frac {t_1t_2} {t_1 + t_2}$, let $V$ be the volume of the pool, and let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be the volume pumped out by each tap per hour. Then we have $t_1v_1=V$, $t_2v_2=V$. If you turn on both taps at once, you're getting $v_1+v_2$ water per hour, so

$$t=\frac V {v_1 + v_2}$$

Except that we don't want $t$ expressed using $v_1$, $v_2$ and $V$, we want to express it in terms of $t_1$ and $t_2$. Here you can use the relations $t_1v_1=V$, $t_2v_2=V$.

Comment: How do you derive the time taken to fill up the pool?

Comment: @Al3 Well, I left that unsolved deliberately. The key is that a tap pumps out *the same volume of water every hour*, so if you write $v$ for that volume, and $V$ is the volume of the pool, the pool will fill up in $V/v$ hours.

Comment: I still don't understand the equation above. Solve directly for me please.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the inverse proportion problems: a pain, indeed. Denote by $\;a,b\;$ the times it takes taps $\;A,B\;$ resp. **each** to fill the pool *alone* .

Were given that

$$\begin{align}&3\left(\frac1a+\frac1b\right)=1\iff a+b=\frac{ab}3&\\{}\\&b=a+5\end{align}$$
Solve the above system ( the answers are ugly)